# Start application on receiving sms from particular number

Tags: android, sms

i want to start an application on receiving sms from a particular number.
i am trying it with  onMessageWaitingIndicatorChanged(boolean mwi){ } method but
i m struggling.
so, anyone there to help me in detail?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to register a broadcast receiver for `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`. The receiver can then check the number of the SMS and start your activity as appropriate.

So, you'll need to:

- Add a `uses-permission` for `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS` to your manifest
- Declare a broadcast receiver in your `<application/>` element in the manfiest:

  ```
  <receiver android:name=".YourReceiverName"> 
      <intent-filter> 
          <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
      </intent-filter> 
  </receiver>
  ```
- Create the receiver class, extending `IntentReceiver`.
- In `onReceiveIntent`, you can get the relevant messages by calling `Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent()` and passing in the intent you're supplied.
- If the number matches the one you want, you can then start an activity by calling `startActivity`

Comment: Chris thanks 4 ur response
Ther is a problem in Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent()
 Perhaps itz deprecated,so Wat to use instead   ..

Comment: You can use `SmsMessage.createFromPdu`. An array of PDUs is available from the Bundle which you can get from the intent - `byte[][] pdus = (byte[][]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");` or so

Answer (score 0):

here is my `onReceive()` method, it works :)

```
public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {
        // get incoming message
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String messages = "";

        // if message available, go on
        if ( extras != null ) {
            // get the array of the message
            Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" );

            // loop through the number of available messages
            for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i ) {
                // create smsmessage from raw pdu
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

                // retrieve contents of message
                String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

                // only accept messages from specified number             
                if(address.equals(0000)){
                             // store the message to database
                    storeToDatabase( contentResolver, sms );
                        // stop message from getting to default app
                    this.abortBroadcast(); 
                }
            }

        }

    }
```